# Unknown column in the field list, parametrized stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've seen a lot of similar problems but none of them solved my problem. This is the code i used to create the stored procedure.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_regUser(
 IN user VARCHAR(100),
 IN name VARCHAR(50),
 IN surname VARCHAR(50),
 IN email VARCHAR(250),
 IN password VARCHAR(250),
 IN telephone VARCHAR(15),
 IN street VARCHAR(120),
 IN postalcode VARCHAR(6),
 IN id INT,
 IN birthdate DATE,
 IN message VARCHAR(320),
 IN photo LONGBLOB,
 IN photoName VARCHAR(50),
 IN role VARCHAR(10)
 )
 BEGIN
INSERT INTO klientet(Perdoruesi,K_Emri,K_Mbiemri,K_Email,Fjalekalimi,K_T_Kontaktues,K_Rruga,K_KodiPostar,ID_Qyteti,K_Datelindja,Mesazh_shtese,Foto,Foto_Emri,Roli) 
 VALUES(user, name, surname, email, password, telephone, street, postalcode, id, birthdate, message, photo, photoName, role);
 END//
 DELIMITER ;
```

And this is the way i call it.

```
CALL sp_regUser('arlind','Arlind','Hajdari','arlind.hajdari@smth.com','perdorimi','0037745231807','Muhaxhiret 13','60000',8,'2016-01-01','miredita',LOAD_FILE('E:/Koala.jpg'),'image.jpg','user')
```

Doing this way, i get an error that says: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'K_Emri' in 'field list'. The columns specified in the insert syntax are correctly corresponding to ones in database, i have no idea whats the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the output of the command?

show columns from klientet;

Comment: The error(output) is shown, as i said it writes: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'K_Emri' in 'field list'. And the klientet table contains all the columns specified in the insert syntax including ID_Klienti as the primary key that is AUTO_INCREMENT and isnt necessary to be in the insert syntax. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: For MySQL to give that message it apparently thinks that column is not in the database; showing the DDL/CREATE for the table could go a long way to diagnosing the root of your issue. In other questions people have posted, similar problems are often due to: (1) pointing to a test|production copy of the db rather than the production|test copy, or (2) having a column with less than obvious characters in it's name such as leading and/or trailing whitespace (such as `\`K_Emri\`` vs `\`K_Emri   \``.

Comment: So you're saying that i have to create the database from the beginning?

Comment: @ArlindHajdari No, I am not saying the database needs recreated, just stating that knowing the exact table structure (by seeing the actual CREATE statement) is very helpful in diagnosing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a trigger that had to be triggered after the insertion to the klientet. Thank you for answers.